# python I have error in nonetype how to solve it

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nonetype

Here I am trying to get domain names of the companies and the company names are stored in new.csv

**The code I have used**

```
import pandas as pd
import clearbit
import json
clearbit.key = 'sk_1915de5d2d7b6e245d6613e3d2188368'
df = pd.read_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")
saved_column = df['Company'].dropna()
print(saved_column)
i=0
res = []
for data in saved_column:   
    n = saved_column[i]
    i = i+1
    data = clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n)
    if data is None null() res.append(data['domain'])
    print(res)
df['domain'] = res
df.to_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv",index = False, skipinitialspace=False)

print("File saved to desktop as new.csv")
```

**output of the code**

```
python ts.py
0                ‎Accenture
1              ‎AND Digital
2                ‎Accenture
3    ‎Kite Consulting Group
4                ‎Capgemini
5             ‎Accenture UK
Name: Company, dtype: object
['accenture.com']
['accenture.com', 'and.digital']
['accenture.com', 'and.digital', 'accenture.com']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ts.py", line 15, in <module>
    res.append(data['domain'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How to give some default value where NoneType encounters and store it with the corresponding company names which is in new.csv

**Expected output to be saved in new.csv**

```
Company                  domain
‎Accenture                accenture.com
‎AND Digital              and.digital
‎Accenture                accenture.com
‎Kite Consulting Group    None
‎Capgemini                capgemini.com
‎Accenture UK             None
```

Comment: Please format the code. There are syntax errors.

Comment: [Catch the Error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and handle it in the except suite.

Comment: I think you need to edit this question: your code isn't valid Python.

Comment: it is a proper code try urself

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n)
try:
   res.append(data['domain'])
except Exception as e:
   #print(e)
   res.append(None)
print(res)
```

Comment: still the same problem this link has the csv file    https://expirebox.com/download/e7ee5d5f0670a8c3be96d7cb90982311.html

Comment: What is the problem? The code in this answer correctly addresses the problem you posted.

Comment: error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ts.py", line 20, in <module>
    res.append(data['domain'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: If you get that error then you are not placing it inside the try...except statement that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
    data=df.loc[i,'data column']
    try:
        res=clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=data)['domain']
        df.loc[i,'res']=res
    except TypeError:
        pass
```